# Access array contents

Tags: php, associative-array

How can I use associative array to display this type of data:

```
array(20) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    ["url"]=>
    string(89) "URL Here"
    ["title"]=>
    string(42) "Title Here"
    ["author_url"]=>
    string(51) "Author Link Here"
    ["author"]=>
    string(14) "Author"
    ["published"]=>
    string(14) "Date"
    ["img_url"]=>
    string(73) "Image Link Here"
    ["teaser"]=>
    string(352) "Lorem Ipsum"
  }

}
```

I know that using `foreach($string as $key=>value)` is the first step but I would like to know how to use it to echo the values then supply them in a html element so the above data should display the contents:

`URL:URL Here
TITLE: Title Here
AUTHOR_URL: Author Link Here
AUTHOR: Author
PUBLISHED: Date
TEASER: Lorem Ipsum`

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: try $string[0]['url']

Comment: Well, why don't you nest two `foreach`?

Comment: hello @Manadh, this would work assuming that there is only one array content how about for multiple?

Comment: you want without foreach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nest a second `foreach` into a first `foreach`:

```
echo '<p>';
foreach($array as $value)
{
    foreach($value as $innerKey => $innerValue)
    {
        echo strtoupper($innerKey).': '.$innerValue;
        echo '<br/>';
    }
}
echo '</p>';
```

Comment: Glad it worked. Please consider accepting this answer as the best suitable for your question and upvoting it as well :)

Comment: I have one thing to add though what if I want to access a specific item only for example the url or author?

Comment: Well, I'd go with an `if` statement such as `if($innerKey == 'url') { echo strtoupper(...`.

Comment: hmm can i do it like setting it to a variable like $url = $innerValue->url?

Comment: @a_miguel6687 First of all, we're talking about `arrays` here, not `object`, so no need for the `->` construction. Second of all, you absolutely can set a variable `$url` to store whatever you need but bear in mind that both keys and values are already stored in `$innerKey` and `$innerValue`.

Comment: had the the idea to combine both key and value

Answer (score 2):

you have a nested array here, you need 2 foreach:

```
foreach ($array as $values) {
    foreach ($values as $key => $v) {
        printf("%s: %s\n", $key, $v);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, no way to handle formatting :

```
print_r($string);
```

More flexible solution, using a formatting recursive function :

```
function custom_print_r($expression, $indent = 1) {
    $buffer = '';
    $str_indent = str_pad('', $indent * 2, ' ');
    $arr_format = "[\n%s\n" . str_pad('', ($indent - 1) * 2 , ' ') . "]";
    $row_format = "$str_indent%s => %s,\n";
    $val_format = "%s";

    if (is_array($expression)) {
        $subbuffer = '';
        foreach($expression as $key => $value) {
            $subbuffer .= sprintf($row_format, $key, custom_print_r($value, $indent + 1));
        }
        $buffer .= sprintf($arr_format, $subbuffer);
    } elseif (is_object($expression)) {
        $subbuffer = '';
        foreach(get_object_vars($expression) as $key => $value) {
            $subbuffer .= sprintf($row_format, $key, custom_print_r($value, $indent + 1));
        }
        $buffer .= sprintf($arr_format, $subbuffer);
    } else {
        $buffer .= sprintf($val_format, $expression);
    }
    return $buffer;
}
$arr = [
    [
    "url" =>"URL Here",
    "title" => "Title Here",
    "author_url" => "Author Link Here",
    "author" => "Author",
    "published" => "Date",
    "img_url" => "Image Link Here",
    "teaser" => "Lorem Ipsum",
  ]
];

echo custom_print_r($arr);

/** Will produce :
[
  0 => [
    url => URL Here,
    title => Title Here,
    author_url => Author Link Here,
    author => Author,
    published => Date,
    img_url => Image Link Here,
    teaser => Lorem Ipsum,

  ],

]
**/
```